# "Рядиться"

Tags: этимология

Какую связь имеют слова "рядиться" в значении "договариваться о плате за работу", "рядиться" в значении "одеваться во что-то" и "ряд" в значении "очередность", "построение предметов"?

Answer (score 1):

Все эти слова родственны, т.е. имеют общее происхождение от слова РЯД. 
Слово РЯД («совокупность однородных предметов, расположенных в одну линию», «совокупность явлений, событий, следующих одно за другим», т.е. ПОРЯДОК) происходит из праслав. *rędъ «ряд»  вследствие изменения у вост. славян носового [ę] в гласн. ['а] (графич. я) и последующей утраты слаб. [ъ] (ср. ст.-cл. Р**Ѧ** ДЪ, польск. rzęd «ряд»). Сюда же* ряда *"уговор, условие" (арханг., вятск., колымск.)
В слове* rędъ суф. -d- и корень тот же, что в *рядити*, *рядиться*, *наряд* и *орудие*.

Первоначальное значение слова *рядити* - 'приводить в порядок, наводить порядок' > 'править, управлять, судить, устраивать'. Глагол *рядитися* является возвратным, образованным от слова *рядити*, и означает 'договариваься о порядке, об условиях; заключать условие'. Отсюда и современное *договор подряда* - 'договор, заключенный на каких-либо условиях'. **Наряд** - это 'одежда, приведенная в порядок'. Кстати, и само слово ПОРЯДОК имеет тот же корень -ряд-.

Comment: Вопрос заключался в том, почему в понятиях торгового договора и одевания один и тот же корень.